# Automatic rejection of Suggested edits?

Tags: support

Two suggested edits to a question of mine were reviewed by "Community" -and rejected. Is behind "Community" a member of the SE-team acting as moderator or something like that, or is there an automatic rejection mechanism of suggested edits after some time passes and no-one reviews them? But I was notified that there were pending suggested edits just *minutes* after the edits were suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this meta answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184993

Basically it is an automatic system that steps in when someone else edits over the top of your edit.  So your edit wasn't necessarily rejected "in a bad way" - just that it was no longer applicable by the time it got there

Comment: Ah, I understand. At the time I too was making edits to my questions, this is why the others got rejected. Thanks.